# Netbeans 7.2: disable the syntax error window?

Tags: netbeans, syntax-error, netbeans-7.2

Is there a way to disable the syntax error window (yellow pop-up) in 7.2?

Searched for this everywhere, but didn't find a definitive answer.  I don't think it is possible, but thought I'd ask.

Thanks!

Comment: What window do you mean exactly? Can you perhaps add a screenshot?